# Where to add index?

Tags: sql, performance, indexing

I'm trying to figure out where I could add an index or modify an existing one to make the query go faster.

Main problem is that I cannot change the query itself, it's generated by Business Objects.

The strange thing is that if I change the WHERE clause to use another table, then the query is really fast!

The query is the following:

```
SELECT Year(listingperformanceindicator.date), 
       Month(listingperformanceindicator.date), 
       categoryflattened.parentname, 
       categoryflattened.groupname, 
       categoryflattened.categoryname, 
       Count(listingperformanceindicator.listingid), 
       ( Count(listingperformanceindicator.listingid) ) / 30, 
       Sum(listingperformanceindicator.listingviews), 
       CASE 
         WHEN ( ( Count(listingperformanceindicator.listingid) ) / 30 ) = 0 THEN 
         0 
         ELSE ( Sum(listingperformanceindicator.listingviews) ) / 
              ( ( Count(listingperformanceindicator.listingid) ) / 30 ) 
       END 
FROM   listingperformanceindicator 
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN categorytolisting 
                     ON ( categorytolisting.siteid = listingperformanceindicator.siteid 
                          AND categorytolisting.listingid = listingperformanceindicator.listingid ) 
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN categoryflattened 
                     ON ( categoryflattened.siteid = categorytolisting.siteid 
                          AND ( categoryflattened.parentid = categorytolisting.categoryid 
                                 OR categoryflattened.categoryid = categorytolisting.categoryid 
                                 OR categoryflattened.groupid = categorytolisting.categoryid ) ) 
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN site ON (site.id=categoryflattened.siteId)
WHERE  --listingperformanceindicator.siteid = 'DED29E78-17B0-423B-A1D1-67E2F3CA864D' --THIS IS REALLY FAST :/
       site.id = 'DED29E78-17B0-423B-A1D1-67E2F3CA864D' --THIS IS REALLY SLOW! :(
       AND categoryflattened.languagecode ='SE'
GROUP  BY Year(listingperformanceindicator.date), 
          Month(listingperformanceindicator.date), 
          categoryflattened.parentname, 
          categoryflattened.groupname, 
          categoryflattened.categoryname
```

I've tried looking at the execution plan but it makes no sense to me :(

Here they are:

fast: http://imageshack.us/a/img211/5755/fastquery.png

slow: http://imageshack.us/a/img823/7227/slowquery.png

Any suggestion appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Add the execution plan please

Comment: Please tag your question with the specific SQL implementation. Anyway, even with appropriate indexes, some implementations don't optimize `OR` conditions (MySQL, for instance).

Comment: There is no table or alias `site` in your query, so where does `site.id` come from?

Comment: Sorry I missed the site table for some strange reason, I must have been tired...

Comment: I have added the links to the plans in the post itself :)

Comment: Been dealing with execution plan hell lately as well. The main thing you're looking for is what columns are being considered in your filtering and what intermediate values are being output as a result. In the slow execution plan, it looks like it's hitting different indexes on the `ListingPerformanceIndicator` table (once to get the data to join to `CategoryToListing`, and another to join that result set back to `ListingPerformanceIndicator`. Figure out what columns are being used as predicates and in the `IX_L...` and `PK_...` index on `ListingPerformanceIndicator` and see if you can combine.

Comment: PS: Good candidates for index consideration are any columns you have a predicate/group by on (Date, SiteID, ListingID) and be sure to `INCLUDE` any columns that you're selecting on so it doesn't need to perform a clustered index scan to get the remaining values. `INCLUDE`d columns can be considered metadata that doesn't get indexed, but are still attached to the indexed records.

Comment: Thank you for the precious info, I will be looking into that :)